# How to get metric labels values from VictoriaMetrics

Tags: prometheus, victoriametrics

There are several API handlers in VictoriaMetrics like /api/v1/labels, but as I can see there is no way to filter one label by another. Let's say I have following structure:
Labels{
**name**,
app,
namespace,
instance
}
where **name** is a metric, app is a service name. So I want to get all distinct metric names where app=service1. Can this be done using just VM's HTTP API?

The only idea I have is to get everything via /api/v1/query and perform some sorting and filtering with a lot of logic which seems to me like an AI invention? cause the query will return a huge amount of data even with timestamp not a range.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you try to use this example. I think it should solve your problem

```
curl -XGET -G 'http://localhost8428/api/v1/label/__name__/values --data-urlencode 'match[]={__name__=~".+", app="service1"}'
```

In that case, the response will be with all metric names which include label value pair like `app="service1"`

For example, my test request

```
curl -XGET -G 'http://localhost:8428/api/v1/label/__name__/values --data-urlencode 'match[]={__name__=~".+", job="vmselect"}'
```

returns something like this

```json
{"status":"success","isPartial":false,"data":["flag","go_cgo_calls_count","go_cpu_count",...,"vm_zstd_block_compress_calls_total","vm_zstd_block_compressed_bytes_total","vm_zstd_block_decompress_calls_total","vm_zstd_block_original_bytes_total","vmselect_request_duration_seconds_bucket","vmselect_request_duration_seconds_count","vmselect_request_duration_seconds_sum"]}
```

There is all metrics name where is `job="vmselect"` label value pair is present